# Windows Server 2008 - Scheduled Task Multiple Users

Tags: user-accounts, windows-task-scheduler, windows-server

I am setting up a scheduled task on a Windows 2008 server to run a utility. I am able to do this without a problem with my user account, but no one else can access it when they login. I need to create some sort of scheduled task that can run under a service account or group that multiple people have access to manage.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in the task scheduler on server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `%windir%\System32\Tasks` (you can copy that, open Run from your Start menu, and paste that in there). You should see your scheduled tasks. You can right-click on the one in question, choose Properties, and then go to the Security tab to change the permissions to allow others to Read the task.